# pymodbus read_input_registers error : ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'

Tags: pymodbus

I'm using pymodbus (v3.0.2) on ubuntu linux server 22.04
using to read modbus rtu device (masibus datalogger)
when I'm  trying to read input register, it some time returning the data which is correct, and most of the time giving this error
"ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'

here is my code to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient

client = ModbusSerialClient(
    method="rtu",
    port="/dev/ttyUSB0",
    stopbits=2,
    bytesize=8,
    parity="N",
    baudrate=9600)
connection = client.connect()
if connection is True:
    print("Modbus Connection Successful")

def read_mbr():
    readreg = client.read_input_registers(0, 15, unit=1).registers
    # print(f'Data = {readreg}')
    return readreg
while(1):
    try:
        data = read_mbr()
        print(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I've tried to add more time detail, but did not worked.

Comment: Does adding the `kwarg` `strict=False` to ModbusSerialClient help?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with `pymodbus`. When you call `client.read_input_registers` an exception occurs (in particular a `ModbusIOException`), pymodbus handles this incorrectly and returns the exception instead of raising it.
The result of `client.read_input_registers(0, 15, unit=1)` becomes therefore a `ModbusIOException` and you are trying to access the `registers` attribute that does not exist.

To avoid this you can:

```py
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusException

...

def read_mbr():
    readreg = client.read_input_registers(0, 15, unit=1)
    if isinstance(readreg, ModbusException):
        raise readreg
    return readreg.registers
```

This way when pymodbus returns the exception instead of raising it you catch it and raise it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to read an input, in your case, you should try : read_holding_registers

Here s a code that works (you need to change with your parameters for the rtu connection) :

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient
from time import sleep

client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', port="COM5", baudrate=19200, parity="E", bytesize=8, stopbits =1, timeout =1.5)

if(client.connect()):
    print("Modbus Connection Successful")
    while(1):
        try:
            unit = 1
            readreg = client.read_holding_registers(0, 15, unit)

            for register in readreg.registers :
                print(register)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        sleep(0.5)

else :
    print("can not connect to modbus device")
```

Tell me if you have any issue with this code.

[image]

Comment: Please explain how your code differs from his and also what issue in his code you are fixing... It looks like this is just a different version of the same code

Comment: @Matteo Zanoni As I said in my answer : "read_holding_registers" you just need to modify read_input_registers to read_holding_registers

Comment: Why change from input registers to holding_registers? They are two different modbus functions...

Comment: As we don't really know how the modbus device of M Houssain works, reading holding registers seams to be the best answer (and it worked for me). The principal difference between holding and input is that holding is R/W and is pretty universal for younger modbus devices (younger is like all modbus devices from 00's to now)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error he is facing...

Comment: It has something to do with this because, x.registers is an exception. It's an exception because we cannot read/query from the modbus device... We cannot query because (surely) it's not an input register but an holding register like every modbus device since the 00's